# Pipe output from one command to another command's non standard input

Tags: shell, pipe, arguments, output

I would like to do something similar to the following:

```
which someapplciation | cd outputfrompreviouscommand
```

The command `which` provides a directory and I would like to be able to make that output my current working directory without using a programming language i.e. `awk`, `bash`, `perl`, etc. and to only use the pipe command.

To further give an example:

```
which vi
```

provides the output

```
/some/dir
```

I would like my working directory to be moved to that directory which I can test by using the `pwd` command which should have the output that matches of `/some/dir`.

Comment: Actually, `which executable` provides the output `/path/to/executable`, not its directory. So, `cd`ing to the output of `which` won't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use a pipe if the second command you are running doesn't read from its standard input. However, you can do something like

```
cd $(which someapplication)
```

or, since you need a directory name for `cd` and not an executable name:

```
cd $(dirname $(which someapplication))
```

The `$(...)` shell operator executes the command within parentheses and substitutes its output into the command line.